# custom text below 2 radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button, haml

I have the follow radio buttons:

```
= f.radio_button :access, [['Public', true], ['Member', false]], label: "Post an update: "
```

However, I want to add custom text in between the radio buttons, eg for the Public option, I want to have a short description below it "Everyone can view", and for the Member option, I want to have another short description below it, "Only members can view". How do I achieve this?

I am using Rails Bootstrap forms.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an in place solution for description fields.
But you could achieve that with either ways:

1. Adding `span` right after your inputs. Just like we [usually](https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/rails-bootstrap-forms#inline-errors) do for error message.
2. Separate you radio button in two button and style them individually.

Comment: How the radio button can be separated into 2 buttons is not clear to me, I tried it but then I had 4 radio buttons (1 extra boolean option for each). Could you provide an example?